# target child with tagname and parent's class name with BEM naming appended to it in scss

Tags: html, css, sass

HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
    <a class="nav__link">click here...</a>
</div>
```

Expected CSS Output:

```
a.nav__link { 
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

My Current SCSS:

```
.nav {
  a&__link {
    text-decoration: error;
  }
}
```

ERROR:

Invalid CSS after "a": expected "{", was "&__link"

"&__link" may only be used at the beginning of a compound selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand well, you want something like that:

```
.nav {
a#{&}__link {
    text-decoration: error;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is `#{&}` here. i am fairly new to sass.

Comment: It's a string interpolation.Just replaces whatever is between brackets. Between brackets you can have parent selector, variable, even a function which returns string.